# WPF: How can I deactivate the Border.Effect when my radio button is checked?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

When I activate my radio button, I want the border effect to be deactivated.

```
<Border x:Name="Border_Rechnung" Width="160" Height="35" Margin="0 30 0 0" Background="#122A4C" CornerRadius="4">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="7" Direction="330" Color="Black" ShadowDepth="4" Opacity="0.3"></DropShadowEffect>
            </Border.Effect>
            <Viewbox Height="29">


                <RadioButton 
                    Click="rb_rechnung_Click"
                    x:Name="rb_rechnung"
                    Content="Rechnung"
                    FontSize="27"
                    Foreground="#BED9FF" 
                    FontFamily="Century Gothic" 
                    Background="#2683FF"
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    BorderBrush="Orange"                            
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                    Margin="5,2,5,2">

                </RadioButton>
            </Viewbox>


        </Border>
```

I have a second question: How can I change the distance from the button in the radio button from like this: [Example 1 - Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KsvK.png)
to like this: [Example 2 - After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx6sT.png)

Comment: You're posting a question. One. Not two. Someone might be able to answer your first one but not the second. Someone else the second but not first. Two posts and you can only mark one as the answer. Set opacity in a style and use a trigger to change it between 0 and more. But be aware dropshadow is a bitmap effect. It'll affect everything inside the border and make it bitty. Don't put everything inside an element has a bitmap effect on it.

Comment: How do you mean it with set opacity in style can you show me a code snippet im new to WPF